# position absolute menu inside motion.div is behind main div

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

Here Menu is a position absolute div. I Increase Zindex but still its behind Wraper .

```
    <Wraper
      as={motion.div}
      initial={{ x: "-100%", opacity: 0 }}
      animate={{ x: "0", opacity: 1 }}
      exit={{ x: "100%", opacity: 0 }}
    >
      <div>{note.text}</div>
      <div className="menu_btn">
        <IconButton onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>
          <i className="fa-solid fa-ellipsis"></i>
        </IconButton>
        <Menu open={open} onClose={() => setOpen(false)}>
          menu text
        </Menu>
      </div>
    </Wraper>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pnQa.png)